# How to combine this 2 ffmpeg commands?

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to combine this 2 ffmpeg commands:

```
"-i videoFile.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -vf pad=$length:height=$length:x=-1:y=-1:color=#195766 resultFile"
```

and

```
"-i videoFile.mp4 -i waterMark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10' resultFile.mp4"
```

Is it possible? How result command will look like?

Answer (score 0):

I hope I have got it right...

The combined command is:

```
ffmpeg -y -i videoFile.mp4 -i waterMark.png -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=384:height=216:x=-1:y=-1:color=#195766[t];[t][1:v]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a resultFile.mp4
```

For **mobile FFmpeg on android** (according to OP's comment):

```
"-y -i ${videoFile.absolutePath} -i $waterMarkPath -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -filter_complex pad=$length:height=$length:x=-1:y=-1:color=#195766[t];[t][1:v]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10[v] -map [v] -map 0:a ${resultFile.absolutePath}"
```

I used the following post as reference: [Create video with 5 images with fadeIn/out effect in ffmpeg](https://superuser.com/questions/833232/create-video-with-5-images-with-fadein-out-effect-in-ffmpeg).

---

Testing:

Creating a sample video file (with audio):

```
ffmpeg -y -r 25 -f lavfi -i testsrc=size=192x108:rate=30 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=400 -f lavfi -i sine=frequency=1000 -filter_complex amerge -vcodec libx265 -crf 17 -pix_fmt yuv420p -acodec aac -ar 22050 -t 30 videoFile.mp4
```

Creating a sample PNG image file:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i mandelbrot=rate=1:size=192x108 -t 1 waterMark.png
```

Executing the combined command:

```
ffmpeg -y -i videoFile.mp4 -i waterMark.png -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -filter_complex "[0:v]pad=$length:$length=216:x=-1:y=-1:color=#195766[t];[t][1:v]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10[v]" -map "[v]" -map 0:a resultFile.mp4
```

---

Result (first frame of the output of the test):
[image]

Comment: *"The arguments `x=-1:y=-1` gave me an error, so I set them to `x=0:y=0`."* What is the error? `-1` should work unless your ffmpeg is ancient. `-1` centers the padding. See [pad filter documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#pad). `[t],[t]` should be `[t];[t]`: see [filtering intro](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) about comma and semi-colon syntax difference.

Comment: @llogan **Thank you**, I had the error message: *Negative values are not acceptable.* You are right, by mistake I executed the test from a temporary folder with ffmpeg.exe version `N-80003-g2f76157` (not even a stable release from 2016). Using version `n4.3.1-29-g89daac5fe2`, it's working. I will try to remember when to use `,` and `;`.

Comment: Thank you much! I use mobile ffmpeg on android, so, i had to make small changes in your command. My result command look like "-y -i ${videoFile.absolutePath} -i $waterMarkPath -c:a copy -c:v libx264 -filter_complex pad=$length:height=$length:x=-1:y=-1:color=#195766[t];[t][1:v]overlay=10:main_h-overlay_h-10[v] -map [v] -map 0:a ${resultFile.absolutePath}"